Twin engine or single engine with parachute, which is safer?
Statistically speaking, if we compare two airplanes: a twin engine (like the Beechcraft Baron) VS a single engine with a parachute (like the Cirrus SR22), if we add up all posible emergency events(engine failure, out of fuel, loss of control, etc) and their probability, on which aircraft do you have more odds to survive?

Don't have data handy but traditionally, singles have always been statistically safer than piston twins, because the single engine performance of a piston twin that is loaded is so bad. Hence the old joke, "the remaining engine takes you directly to the scene of the crash".  Richard Collins in FLYING magazine used to write about this all the time. A parachute would raise SE safety further.

@JohnK  it is safe to say a single is also safer in the case of a jet engine?. Let's say the Cirrsu Vision Jet VS a Embraer Phenom 100

If we add data for twin-engine jets, the stats probably tip toward the twins, just because there are so many Boeings & Airbus & Gulfstreams & Lears & whatnot flying around with safety stats well above any GA, single or twin. Basically zero single engine anythings are maintained & operated at Part 121 standards, and not many at Part 135.

@RalphJ yes once the single engine climb exceeds, say, 500 fpm or so in marginal conditions (loaded, hot) the risks drop off sharply. So turboprops and jets don't apply to this when I say twins because they can generally get away when one quits during takeoff. The piston twin might give you 2-300 fpm at gross wt, but that's only if you fly it perfectly, on blue line, 5 deg into the live engine, all of that. At 5000 ft density alt, gross wt, the good engine is more or less just flattening your glide.

@Gabe no because twin jets generally have oodles of reserve power and can climb decently single engine. Take away half the thrust of a jet, and it still might climb at 1000-2000 fpm. Take away half the power of a turboprop, you still get 500-1000 fpm, Take away half the power of a Piper Seminole, when loaded at gross, and it's barely enough for level flight plus enough for a couple hundred fpm of climb if you fly it properly. In the case of a jet, I'd go with the Phenom unless its engine out performance was really bad.

@RalphJ yeah that's a good point, the Part they operate in definitely has an impact. There is actually a company called "Verijet" which charters the  Cirrus VisionJet (exclusively for that matter), don't know if you've heard about it. Yeah, would be interesting to make a comparison with the counterpart flying under the same Part.
